# mysql maths based query

Tags: mysql, math

I have a table of firearms in my game, it has 3 fields:

```
Name       dmg    timer
------------------------
Pistol     5      30
Shotgun    10     45
Sniper     16     60
```

The timer represents how often in seconds it can be shot. Theres a lot more rows than this, but..

I want to pull them in order of rate of fire, which one can damage the most every minute. So the pistol would do 10 damage every minute, the shotgun 12.5, the sniper 16.

How would I do this as a query?

```
SELECT * FROM firearms ORDER BY ?
```

It's probably some basic math but I'm not thinking clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to calculate a weighted damage, I think something like this would do:

```
SELECT * FROM firearms ORDER BY (dmg * (60/timer)) desc
```

Comment: Should be 60/timer, not timer/60, I think.

Comment: Ah yes, just corrected. I thought it was the length of time the weapon could be fired for, but that obviously doesn't make sense for a sniper rifle! :D

Comment: That would be an **awesome** sniper rifle... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM firearms ORDER BY dmg/timer desc
```

- to get most damaging first.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name,
    dmg,
    timer, 
    (dmg * (60 / timer)) as  
FROM firearms 
ORDER BY xx desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  dmg*60.0/timer AS DamagePerMinute,
  *
FROM firearms 
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, (dmg/timer) FROM Weapons ORDER BY (dmg/timer)
```

returns all the weapons in the database by their DPS (damage per second), with two columns: the name, and the DPS.